# How to integrate iOS Framework into Cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My company has an iOS SDK/framework that I've been asked to implement a Cocoapod for to help the install process.

I'm a C#/.Net developer by trade, so this is more of a task than it probably should be!

I successfully followed a guide over at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332 which walks through setting up a cocoapod, but doesn't include any Framework integration.

Our framework appears to be a combination of objective-C and swift files.

I then tried setting up another cocoapod project and adding my framework file under Pods>Frameworks>iOS>myFramework.framework.

Once I did this, I tried `pod install` on the example project which looked like it installed my pod, but I see no reference to the framework.

I also tried adding my framework via the podspec metadata file in s.ios.vendored_frameworks, to no avail...

Why on earth is something that's supposed to make our lives easier so complicated to setup!?

Help most appreciated.

Dave

`podfile`
    use_frameworks!

```
target 'iOS_sdk_Example' do
  pod 'iOS_sdk', :path => '../'

  target 'iOS_sdk_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

Comment: Have you switched to the `.xcworkspace` file that cocoapods generates after you run `pod install` on your example project?

Comment: @Wez I have indeed, that is a basic :)

Comment: Have you created a bridging-header file and connected it under the app settings General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries? If your framework contains objective-c this is necessary.

Comment: @matiastofteby I have not, will look that up now.

Comment: What does your example project `Podfile` look like?

Comment: Sorry! You have to add the header file under Build Settings -> Swift Compiler General. Then you can add the framework to the Linked Framework and Libraries if necessary. Also if your library uses Embedded Libraries you have to add the frame work to there right above the Linked Framework etc.

Comment: @wez added the podfile to the post, note that this doesn't actually sit under the example project, but under Pods project.